# mustang and v8 - install fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to install mustang (with bundle install) on Ubuntu.

I have installed scons on my system.

I get the following error:

```
Installing mustang (0.2.2) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/scope/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lv8... yes
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for ruby.h... yes
checking for v8.h... yes
checking for v8-debug.h... yes
checking for v8-profiler.h... no
creating Makefile

make
g++ -I. -I/home/scope/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/home/scope/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/scope/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_RUBY_H -DHAVE_V8_H -DHAVE_V8_DEBUG_H  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC   -o v8_string.o -c v8_string.cpp
In file included from v8_string.cpp:2:
v8_cast.h:21: error: ‘RegExp’ was not declared in this scope
v8_cast.h:21: error: template argument 1 is invalid
make: *** [v8_string.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Ubuntu version? Have you installed `libv8-dev`? It works with my 11.10 ubuntu.

Comment: A very similar issue is in the tracker but its last entry is june 20/2011, so it doesn't look like its going to be fixed any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that mustang requires libv8 version >= 3.0, you may be experiencing the same problem reported in [issue #14](https://github.com/nu7hatch/mustang/issues/14) on mustang's issue tracker.